# Rxdb migration is not running

Tags: pouchdb, rxdb

I have a schema with version 0, and 4k docs with it.
Changing version to 1, have the following strategy:

```
  autoMigrate: true,
  migrationStrategies: {
    1: (r: any) => {
      debugger;
      console.log(r);
      return r;
    }
  },
```

reload the page, nothing is printed, debugger is not stopped.
I tried to follow the code in `data-migration.js`, it looks like `getBatchOfOldCollection` returns an empty batch.
What can cause it?
I tried to run the migration manually with the same result.

Comment: This is really strange. I think you should create a standalone testcase because this is likely a bug.